# Kafka Producer not producing message on SSL using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to integrate KAFKA with Spring, my JAVA application is communicating with the KAFKA server and I am also recieving the messages when I run the application using HTTP.

Now I want to add SSL on KAFKA now using Spring and I have done the changes specified on [SSL KAFKA](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl) and [SPRING KAFKA](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/using-apache-kafka-for-integration-and-data-processing-pipelines-with-spring)

The communication happens properly when I run the producer and consumer using command line (with SSL), But when I change the configuration of Java application and try to produce and consume the message on a topic the consumer works fine and I am getting the messages on the specified topic.

But the producer is not working as expected the messages sent from the JAVA application producer aren't received on consumer (niether command line nor JAVA app consumer).

I have googled it but didn't find an answer to it. Any pointers?

PS: KAFKA Version kafka 0.9.0.0, JAVA 7, and the SSL properties used with Spring are as below:

```
<prop key="ssl.keystore.location">/keystore.jks</prop>
<prop key="ssl.keystore.password">password</prop>
<prop key="ssl.key.password">password</prop>
<prop key="security.protocol">SSL</prop>
<prop key="ssl.truststore.location">/truststore.jks</prop>
<prop key="ssl.truststore.password">password</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this property:

```
ssl.protocol=SSL
```

Here are all the property needed for producer:

```
{
ssl.protocol=SSL
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/home/vagrant/securityDemo/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/home/vagrant/securityDemo/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
}
```

Reference - working code: https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9/blob/master/src/main/resources/Producer.Properties

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am trying to do it using Spring and i have already added that protocol tag in XML but it didnt help.

Comment: Any Error logs?? from Kafka side?. Can you try to compare Java code with the below one. It worked for me.    https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9/blob/master/src/main/java/com/symantec/cpe/kafka/producer/KafkaProducerNewJava.java